# How do I configure custom keyboard layout switching?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I'm using three keyboard layouts. One of them I use rarely, so I want to have one shortcut to switch between two layouts and another one to switch to the third one. Switching between 3 layouts using a single shortcut is really inconvenient.

How do I set xkb to do that?

Comment: what plugin are you using for switching?

Comment: What do you mean by "plugin"?

Comment: I mean what desktop environment do you use (gnome? xfce? kde?) and what panel plugin to display/switch keyboards. For example, is it the xfce4-xkb-plugin?

Comment: @cipricus I tried different desktop environments (Unity, Gnome Shell, KDE, awesome), ended up using Xfce. I have been using X Neural Switcher for some time, but it has its limitations. So this question is still open.

Comment: Also I have an impression that this can be achieved using xkb only,  it's just too complicated for beginners like me.

Comment: Xfce uses xkb with the xfce4-xkb-plugin for layouts, and the later cannot do what you ask. initially i had posted an answer here just to make the proper settings for a single shortcut and later realized that you wanted a second shortcut just for the third layout. not possible

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that what you are asking is possible, while the question is too localized anyway. Keeping a third layout in reserve and activating it by shortcut seems a far more inconvenient procedure to be set even if it were possible than using one shortcut to switch between three layouts.

Comment: I'm on Xubuntu 12.04, and it seems like this problem is solved, though several times I had my settings reset to default. Thanks for your solution, now I know what I'll do next time this happens.

Comment: what do you mean solved? you got a way of having a second shortcut for the third layout?

Comment: you mentioned in one of the previous edits that there was a problem with xfce4-xkb-plugin, with settings being reset after reboot.

Comment: about convenience - well, that's personal. When I used Windows, there was a small utility called [keyla](http://code.google.com/p/keyla/wiki/ru_Main). Using this utility I set up switching between first two layouts to Caps,the third one was activated by Shift+Caps, and it really worked for me.  Now things have changed a bit and I would appreciate having separate shortcut for each layout.